# Incremental Backup of iPhoto Library

Tags: macos, finder, backup, photos.app

I have an external hard drive, not always connected to my laptop. I don't use it for Time Machine, as it's not big enough, and most of my important documents are on DropBox... Plus I only connect it a few minutes per week when I need to copy something.

For iPhoto, I found the Library file and I manually copy it to my external drive once in a while. The problem I have with that, is the file is growing big (22GB last I checked), and I feel like it's a waste to wait so long for copying the entire file, while I'm really only adding the last GB for example.

Is there a way to just add the increment?

Keep in mind again I only connect my external drive when needed.

Comment: You could use Time Machine only for the iPhoto library by excluding all the other folders from the backup. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.

The first thing to realise is that the iPhoto Library is a folder, not a file. The Finder shows it as a file for end-user convenience, but it really is a folder.

There are many tools to quickly mirror a folder from a source to a destination. I would recommend using `rsync`.

Comment: Note that `rsync` is a command line tool (to be used in a Terminal). Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: This sounds like what I am looking for. Will try when I get the chance. Is this tool built-in OSX or am I supposed to download it somewhere?

Comment: There is a built-in version of rsync on Mac OS X but it's old (2.6.9; current version is 3.1.0). It works though. If you want the very last version (better management of xattr and stuff), I recommend you use Homebrew (http://brew.sh) to install it.

Comment: I'm ready to test rsync now (it's been a while I know), but yes, this looks complicated! Any tips to do a simple backup as explained? One-time, no schedules, just backing up the diff?

Comment: I'll add a comment soon to explain

Comment: All in a Terminal, first install Homebrew (see http://brew.sh). Then install rsync 3.0.9 (`brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/109dca908c6499116e07483d7afe8a1c3ef63ad6/rsync.rb`). Then, to do the actual rsync, type `/usr/local/bin/rsync -avXAH --delete PATH_TO_SOURCE_FOLDER PATH_TO_DEST_FOLDER` where PATH_TO_SOURCE_FOLDER is the full path to the destination folder *without* a trailing slash (presumably `~/Pictures/iPhoto\ Library.photolibrary`) and PATH_TO_DEST_FOLDER is the full path to the dest folder **with** a trailing slash.

Comment: If you're not familiar with command-line utilities, you might want to have a look at CCC (http://www.bombich.com/index.html) which uses rsync but hides the ugly work. However, this application is not free (anymore). 

Comment: If you want to use rsync via the command-line, I'd recommend you remove the `--delete` option the first time to avoid accidental removal of files that should not be removed. When you have verified the command line works as expected, you can add the `--delete` option again.

Comment: Don't hesitate to contact me if you need further instructions/clarifications.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I need to download XCode to use Brew. Downloading...

Comment: @Frizlab can you also recommend options, that I need to include? My version is `rsync -va src/ dst`

Comment: @skywinder Your version should be enough for syncing the iPhoto Library (either with the system or homebrew version of rsync). See one of my comment above for a more complete set of options. I'm not sure of the arguments for the system version of rsync.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any app that does incremental back ups will back up the iPhoto Library. Some suggestions:

Chronosync http://www.econtechnologies.com/pages/cs/chrono_overview.html

DejaVu http://propagandaprod.com

Carbon Copy Cloner - http://www.bombich.com

I've used all of these at different times and changed for various reasons. But they all work perfectly well. All are straightforward to set up.